# Infinite allowed Lateness for Apache Flink Windows

Tags: apache-flink

I have following use case, sorry if there is an obvious solution but I am very new to Flink:

Events (containing a value of interest) in a stream are supposed to be assigned to a window based on event-time. In my case events do not only arrive out of order and late but also events are versioned. By that, I mean, that for a given event-time two events may arrive. In this case the window should fire again. The time between the arrival of these events might be days (or even weeks). I already found the allowed Lateness option for windows. Is this a possible solution or would this amount in to many windows that can not be discarded, since another event might still arrive (this basically boils down to the questions, if windows are persisted or kept in memory).

Thanks

Comment: The way windows are stored (disk vs memory) depends on the [state backend](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/ops/state/state_backends.html) you're using. The RocksDBStateBackend will store the window state in disk while MemoryStateBackend and FsStateBackend will do it in memory. Beware that this should not be your only concern, maintaining windows forever might cause CPU problems too.

Answer (score 1):

In general the allowed lateness needs to be finite in order to avoid keeping an unbounded amount of state. But you can configure Flink to use the RocksDBStateBackend, which will spill state to disk, allowing for as much state as your local disks can hold.

If very late events are rare, you might be better off accommodating them in some special way, rather than burdening a general purpose pipeline with the overhead of all that state.

Comment: Can you please give an example of some way to `accommodating them in some special way`? For example in case of transactions, user/ad events,... dedup.

Comment: I was alluding to the idea of sending extremely late events to a side output, and from there to a separate sink that is read by another job. If these events are rare, then that "helper job" can afford to load the information necessary to handle each late event from external databases, etc.